# Rubinius does not recognize methods in the File class

Tags: ruby, rubinius

I have a project that has alot of file manipulation.  I am trying out Rubinius because I need to be able to compile the code.  When I try to run code that includes

```
if Dir.exist?(file_path)
```

I get this error:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `exist?' on Dir (Class)
```

Is there something I need to include to get this recognized?  Btw, I have also tried Dir.exists? since it is an alias, and that didn't work either.  Is the issue that this method didn't exist in 1.8.7?  I can't seem to find a list of

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue was that Rubinius is using 1.8.7 and this method didn't exist then.